# How to Contract Indices Using Feyncalc

Tags: tensors, feyncalc

I am slowly learning how to use Feyncalc, and I have a quick question.

I have a third rank tensor B[mu,nu,tao] and I also have a four-vector FV[W,mu].  I would like to contract the first two indices of "B" to get a four-vector, and then contract the result with "W" to obtain a scalar result.  So I wrote this:

res=Contract[B[mu,mu,tao]*FV[W,tao]]

But this does not seem to be working, I get error messages  and/or results that don't make sense.  Is there a better way to write the formula for "res"?  Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: It seems `DeclareFCTensor[B]; Contract[B[mu, nu, tao] FV[W, tao]]` doesn't work.  In my program [Package-X](https://packagex.hepforge.org), you would do `Contract[LTensor[B, mu, nu, tau] LTensor[W, tau]]`.  I wonder what the analog of `LTensor` in FeynCalc is.

Comment: The indices inside `B` should be wrapped into `LorentzIndex`: `DeclareFCTensor[B]; Contract[B[LorentzIndex[mu], LorentzIndex[mu], LorentzIndex[tao]]* FV[W, tao]]`. This is because FeynCalc internally "sees"  FV[W,tao] as Pair[LorentzIndex[tao], Momentum[W]], so that B must be written in a similar fashion.

Comment: Thank you vsht. I tried this code: DeclareFCTensor[B]. Then I wrote H:=Contract[B[LorentzIndex[mu],LorentzIndex[mu],LorentzIndex[tao]]*FV[W,tao]. And I also wrote B[mu_,nu_,tao_]:=MT[mu,nu]*FV[v,tao]. This failed.  So I am flummoxed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `B` is a generic tensor, you have to explicitly wrap the indices
into `LorentzIndex`

```
DeclareFCTensor[B]; 
Contract[B[LorentzIndex[mu], LorentzIndex[mu], LorentzIndex[tao]]* FV[W, tao]]
```

Notice that `DeclareFCTensor` is only needed if you also want to be able to
uncontract the indices as in

```
Uncontract[B[LorentzIndex[mu], LorentzIndex[mu], Momentum[W]], W, 
 Pair -> All]
```

Otherwise you could also omit `DeclareFCTensor`.

Now, if `B` is just a shortcut for a tensor made out of products of 4-vectors and metric
tensors, things become much simpler: you can define it as one would define
a generic function in Mathematica

```
B[mu_,nu_,tao_]:=MT[mu,nu]*FV[v,tao]
Contract[B[mu, mu, tao]*FV[W, tao]]
```

Notice that

```
Contract[B[LorentzIndex[mu], LorentzIndex[mu], LorentzIndex[tao]]*
  FV[W, tao]]
```

also works, because `LorentzIndex[LorentzIndex[mu]]` is evaluated to `LorentzIndex[mu]`.

Extended FeynCalc-related questions are probably best asked in the new forum on GitHub (which is much easier to use than the old, now retired, mailing list)

https://github.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/discussions

Comment: Thanks vsht.  In the future I will use GitHub.  I am still getting a crazy result. Please note that before I ran this code, I shut down and restarted my computer, and reloaded Feyncalc, so hopefully this cleared any cache. I will now show the exact code and the exact result.... `B1[La_,be_,cu_]:=MT[be,cu]*FV[v,La];` `res=Contract[B1[mu,mu,om]]`  The crazy result is a sum of three fractions all having the same denominator which is 2mu.  The sum of these three numerators is `-(2mu-om)Bsubscript0(mu,mu,om)-Asubscript0(om)+Asubscript0(mu)`  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is because B1 and A0 are already defined in FeynCalc to denote something else (Passarino-Veltman functions). Hence, when you try to use them as tensors, things get maximally messed up. So just use different names that are still free. You can always use `?myVar` to check if there are any definitions already attached to `myVar`. If not, you will see something like `Missing[UnknownSymbol,myVar]`

Comment: Thank you vsht!  I will try this when I get home.

Comment: I have accepted this answer.  Also, I posted a separate issue at GitHub (under the username "Ferrylodge").  Thanks again.